# Elasticsearch: Search over most frequent matches / terms without TF or IDF adjustment

Tags: elasticsearch

we are working on a text-based search (via the famous "Type your search here" input box) that computes the score over multiple fields and shows the best results. It's basically a bool query with a mixture of "term" and "match" over many different fields (using fuzzyness, ngram, edge-ngrams and others).

We want the best results (being most "popular") to show up first (thus get the highest score). However the default TF-IDF algorithm of lucene gives us the exact opposite. Image you look for a vendor that exists in 30% of all index entries. It will have a very high IDF and be ranked very low. We just want the exact opposite of that - give us the most frequent first(!).

Trying our best luck with the the "cross-field" query did not work out since we want to combine different query types with "bool".

Now, what we "found out" is that using Okapi BM25 with k1=0 and b=0 almost(?) behaves like a similarity that ignores TF (term frequency) and IDF (inverse document frequency). However we feel unsure if this really is the way to go.

Can you give us some feedback on that, please?

Is this the way to go or for our "problem" is there better waiting to be discovered?

---

### update

I try to make my question more clear (sorry for any confusion):

Let's say we have an index of cars...

```
{id: 1, vendor: Opel, model: Astra, engine: 90hp gasoline}
{id: 2, vendor: Opel, model: Astra, engine: 100hp diesel}
{id: 3, vendor: Opel, model: Astra, engine: 120hp gasoline}
{id: 4, vendor: Chevrolet, model: Astro, engine: 120hp gasoline}
```

We do a "full text search" over the current user input **"astr"**

All fields (vendor, model + engine) are analyzed using the "edge ngram" analyzer {min:2, max:10} to support prefix search.

the input "astr" would match all entries #1 - #4 (it's the beginning of "Astra" and "Astro", so all entries would contain an edge ngram match)

the IDF of "Astr**a**" is log(4/3) ~= 0,287

the IDF of "Astr**o**" is log(4/1) ~= 1,386

so #4 would be ranked better due to the IDF

However, we want the exact opposite: The "more frequent" (= "more popular") car should be ranked higher.

note: the "cross fields" query will not be sufficient since we combine several **different** queries (fuzzy, edge ngram, raw) into **one large bool query**

Comment: So, are you saying that the scoring influence of matches on the *vendor field* is lower than you'd like when the document-frequency of the search term is high?   (BM25 only lets you tune the impact of term-frequency and length-normalization, not IDF).

Comment: BM25 indeed only seems to affect TF but not IDF :-P

Comment: so is there any way of getting the "most frequent" matches before the "less frequent" ones?

Comment: So, for example:  a search for ["excel"] should return "Microsoft Excel 2013" (vendor: Microsoft) ahead of "PDF to Excel Enterprise" (vendor: Cogniview Systems Ltd.) because *Microsoft* (vendor) appears more frequently in your collection than *Cogniview* (vendor)?

Comment: Thanks for the example.  You're looking for "the most popular (car?)" present in your search results, and you want to be able to re-order (or otherwise influence) your suggestions based on this measurement.  In most cases, I believe this would typically require two round-trips, but I'll post a solution for doing this example in one (though probably without the nuance you're ultimately going to want.)

Comment: Try [custom similarity](https://github.com/beowulfenator/elasticsearch-custom-similarity-provider) class. It worked for me. IDF calculation is just a function that receives docFreq and numDocs - you can easily invert the default formula or implement your own.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to follow this general process:

1. Run a complex, custom search query.
2. Examine the results to determine how much each vendor dominates within the result set
3. Reorder the results, boosting cars with more dominant vendors.

---

**Solution 1** (most flexible, least performant)

You can get the information for #2 using a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the vendor field.

Then you can re-query with the necessary derived boosts (costing a second round-trip)

**OR**

**Solution 2** (least flexible, most performant)

If you're content to let `vendor popularity` trump `_score`, you can do the following:

- Run a zero-result query (your current fuzzy match query)
- ... with a [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation on `vendor`
- ... ... with a [Top Hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub-aggregation sorted by `_score` descending.

Then your `[astr]` query results within the aggregation result will look like this:

```
[Opel bucket]
Astra 90hp
Astra 100hp diesel
Astra 120hp
Ascona 144hp (if you had fuzziness 2)
Ascona 230hp (if you had fuzziness 2)

[Chevrolet bucket]
Astro 120hp
Alero 140hp (if you had fuzziness 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use document frequency to *boost* your results, try rolling your own [script_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/script-score.html) function inside a `function_score` clause.  You can access document frequency of a term inside your scoring function via [term statistics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_statistics_2).

You may discover that an unintended consequence of this approach is that common/generic terms like `Corp`, `Solutions`, `Computer`, `Inc`, etc will have an outsize influence on your score if you don't explicitly scrub them out as stopwords.

Comment: no - we want to effectively disable IDF und TF from the ranking formula. this is independent of boosting. or whatever is required to get the "most frequent" terms instead of the "most specific" ones.

Comment: Ignoring the "most frequent" mechanism:  It sounds like you want a [constant score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html), which will just return 1 if your query matches and 0 if not.  It's basically the same as a filter, except since you ultimately want to have this contribute to the overall score, that (optionally boosted) 1 becomes available to your scoring strategy.

Comment: using constant_score would make the query behave like a filter like you said, but we still want some scoring. e.g. we have a fuzzy text match that should be better or worse depending on the fuzzyness of the match (= levenshtein distance). don't know if all this can be done in a function_score and if the performance would be still acceptable.

Comment: Right.  You can wrap function_score and constant_score queries implementing your various strategies into a bool query to get a sum of the different scores.

Comment: Performance is a different issue.  Fuzzy queries can impact performance pretty heavily.  Make sure you need it, and use as little fuzz as possible if you do.